# Radial gradient wipe in square

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm currently working on a quite tricky combination of things the designer I work on this project with came up with.

It is a rectangle filled with a gradient. Then a radial wipe to clean the whole scene and then the gradient re-appears and it starts again after a small delay.

I created something that is close but not quite it.

https://codepen.io/JanaKemmer/pen/bGvyKxZ

I basically did a polygon clip path keyframe animation over the gradient. But because of the way I built it it basically stops at each keyframe. So it is very jittery. If it wouldn't stop at the keyframes it would be perfect.

I found a similair effect here through another thread here that is also not that far from what I want to achieve: https://codepen.io/JanaKemmer/pen/bGvPzxm

HTML

```
<div class="gradient"></div>
<div class="reveal"></div>
```

CSS

```
.gradient {
  background: conic-gradient(rgba(177, 216, 224, 1), rgba(242, 231, 203));
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.reveal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 8s rectangleDelay infinite; 
  background: white;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes rectangleDelay {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 50% 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 50% 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 50% 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 50% 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 50% 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0);
  }
}
```

TL;DR: I am looking for a solution that achieves the effect from the first codepen without it stopping at the keyframe points.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `animation: 8s rectangleDelay infinite linear;` <-- adding linear in the animation

Comment: I feel so stupid. That actually does it!! Thank you so much. Sometimes I miss the most obvious stuff! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Have you seen this approach? https://codepen.io/GGCF/pen/YzevpGP

Comment: "*//Edit: Allready solved, working code updated*" - please put the "working code" in an answer *not* the question. Then - assuming no better answers are received beforehand (at your own judgement) - accept that answer in a couple of days to show the system that the question has been answered.